# Old questions not showing in the questions list?

Tags: discussion, support

Whenever I ask a question, if there is no activity on the question on first day, it is hard to find it in the **Questions** list. So if the question is lucky enough to be spotted by someone who can answer it, on the first day, then it get enough attention. Otherwise it is buried in the new Questions list.

My question is, what should we do if the question is not getting attention?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll just link to the main meta here: [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/getting-attention-for-unanswered-questions)

Sergey already lists the top two options, but here is their advice verbatim:

> 1. You can "bump" your question by editing the question to **provide status and progress updates resulting from your own continued efforts to answer the question yourself**. I usually do that unless I really hit a dead end with no further clues to follow. Some times I eventually bring about enough understanding to realise the answer, and thus post a resolution to my own problem.
> 2. If you have at [least 75 rep points](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), you can offer a **bounty**, promising to give some of your points to the person who correctly answers your question.
> 3. **Upvote** the original question - every upvote helps increase its profile on the site.
> 4. Use the **share** button beneath the original question to advertise it to your networks
>
> **Do not post your question a second time**, as it will be closed as a duplicate of your first question.

Not sure how you're supposed to upvote your own question but...yeah their editing advice is solid. Keep trying to solve the problem. Add information about what else you've tried.

Comment: I'm pretty sure #3 applies to an unanswered "other person's" question that you're interested in seeing an answer for.

Answer (score 7):

You have some options.

- First you could set a [bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to your question to get more attention from users.
- If the question wasn't answered after some time (even with bounty) you can edit it and put more information that could help the people to answer it. The updated question will be then put to the top again.

Comment: Yes, editing your post with *improvements* will bring it to the top of the "active" view. Please take care, however, to avoid [spurious edits](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2110/spurious-edits).

Comment: I use the editing approach when improvements are possible.

Comment: I could always bounty 1k rep so I can cross 100k again?

Comment: @sfdcfox Not always! Probably not even tomorrow!